# Why aren't my php classes working after an ajax call

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax

This is my index.php file when the user isn't logged in it loads an login page else it loads the app

```
$user = new User();
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <title>Page Title</title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="assets/css/master.css"/>
        <script src="assets/js/functions.js?<? filectime('assets/js/functions.js') ?>"></script>

        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

        <script src="assets/vendor/jquery-validation/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
        <script src="assets/vendor/jquery-validation/additional-methods.min.js"></script>

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets\vendor\bootstrap\dist\css\bootstrap.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="main-wrapper container-fluid">
        <?
        if($user->isLoggedIn()) {
            include_once 'app/index.php';
        } else {
            include_once 'files/auth/login.php';
        }
        ?>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

This is the login.php file that gets loaded in whe the user is not logged in

```
 <div class="login-card">
    <form id="sign-in-form">
        <h2>Sign in</h2>
        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="text" name="username" required class="form-control" placeholder="Username">
            <input type="password" name="password" required class="form-control" placeholder="Password">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block">sign in</button>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
<div class="login-links">
    <a href="" id="register-link">Create an account</a>
    <a href="" class="grid-justify-end">Forgot password</a>
</div>

<script src="files/auth/js/login.js?<?= filemtime('files/auth/js/login.js') ?>"></script>
```

When a user clicks on create an account an Ajax function gets called and it loads the register page in the main-wrapper div but when it gets loaded in my php class User is undefiend? and the variable $user in index.php is also undefiend

Comment: I am not sure I understand your logic here, can you explain the flow better/

Comment: You should `include` the `User class` file in your page.

Comment: @JayBlanchard when you go in to my website it loads the index.php file(first block of code) then it checks via the User class loaded in $user variable if the user is logged in or not. if not it loads the login page wich works fine. I added an event listener on the <a> tag create an account when the user clicks on that tag it fires up an ajax load function that loads the register .php file similar to the login page but after the ajax call my classes aren't loaded in and i cant use the $user variable in the index.php eventough i loaded the register page in the div main wrapper in my index file

Comment: What is the name of your `User Class` file?

Comment: The remote file is not going to be aware of what you loaded locally unless you send that information with the AJAX call.

Comment: @Talk2Nit the name of the User class is User.php class name User

Comment: @JayBlanchard But it gets loaded in a div in the index it should know what is allready in my index file right?

Comment: No. AJAX works with variables in the remote PHP file, not the local (at least not the way you have it setup). If you want that data displayed you have to send it with the AJAX request.

Comment: @JayBlanchard then how should i set it up so ajax knows whats allready in my index?

Comment: You're using jQuery, so you can get the value of anything loaded in the current page before making the AJAX request.

Comment: So what you're saying is the way i want it to work is impossible?

Comment: Not at all, you just may have to rethink your logic a bit. When you click the `<a>` tag to create, you send what you know via the AJAX request.

Comment: @JayBlanchard Got a website or an example for me?

Comment: People do this with AJAX all of the time, it's a fairly basic AJAX interaction.

Answer (score -1):

try including the file containing User Class in your register file.

Comment: You may be right, but you can improve your answer by showing _where_ and _what_ to include.

Comment: Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'DB' not found in D:\Xampp\htdocs\Edugrad\classes\User.php:9 Stack trace: #0 D:\Xampp\htdocs\Edugrad\files\auth\register.php(3): User->__construct() #1 {main} thrown in D:\Xampp\htdocs\Edugrad\classes\User.php on line 9

Answer (score -1):

Like this

`include 'path/to/users_phph_file/Users.php';
$user = new User();`

if you folder structure looks like this:

root
-classes
--users.php
index.php

then 

`include 'classes/Users.php';
$user = new User();`

Comment: Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'DB' not found in D:\Xampp\htdocs\Edugrad\classes\User.php:9 Stack trace: #0 D:\Xampp\htdocs\Edugrad\files\auth\register.php(3): User->__construct() #1 {main} thrown in D:\Xampp\htdocs\Edugrad\classes\User.php on line 9
That's the error i then get.

Comment: @Midorikawa - that is the _next_ error in a sequence of errors. You need to follow them up the chain and `include` the necessary files.